# Split or substitute strings with wildcards in R

Tags: regex, r

I have the following vector:

```
a <- c("abc_lvl1", "def_lvl2")
```

I basically want to split into two vectors:
`("abc", "def")` and `("lvl1", "lvl2)`. I know how to substitute with sub:

```
sub(".*_", "", a)
[1] "lvl1" "lvl2"
```

I think this translates into "Search for any number of any characters before "_" and replace with nothing." Accordingly - i thought - this should give me the other desired vector:

`sub("_*.", "", a)`, but it removes just the leading character:

```
[1] "bc_lvl1" "ef_lvl2"
```

Where do i mess up? 
This is essentially the equivalent for the "text-to-columns"-function in excel.

Comment: Just use `strsplit`?

Comment: that seems legit, but it creates a list of vectors, which i would need to split again: strsplit(a, "_")
[[1]]
[1] "abc"  "lvl1"

[[2]]
[1] "def"  "lvl2"

Comment: `*` means zero or more occurrences of the prior character and `.` means any character so `_*.` removes zero underscores followed by one character.  You want `_.*` which will remove underscore followed by all further occurrences of any character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Here are a few, some using packages, and others with base R.

Given:

```
a <- c("abc_lvl1", "def_lvl2")
```

Here are some options:

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(a, "_", TRUE))

matrix(scan(what = "", text = a, sep = "_"), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

scan(text = a, sep = "_", what = list("", "")) ## a list

library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(data.table(a), "a", "_")

library(data.table)
setDT(tstrsplit(a, "_"))[]

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data_frame(a) %>%
  separate(a, into = c("this", "that"))

library(reshape2)
colsplit(a, "_", c("this", "that"))

library(stringi)
t(stri_split_fixed(a, "_", simplify = TRUE))

library(iotools)
mstrsplit(a, "_")  # Matrix
dstrsplit(a, col_types = c("character", "character"), "_") # data.frame

library(gsubfn)
read.pattern(text = a, pattern = "(.*)_(.*)")
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `read.csv/read.table` and specify the `sep="_"`.  It will split the strings into two columns.

```
read.csv(text=a, sep="_", header=FALSE)
```

Comment: I am really sorry for the excel-comment. This was just "free association". Those vectors are not related to excel-files. I am sorry.

Comment: @nouse I didn't really read your excel-files comment.  This is a way to split up into columns

Comment: which is what i misunderstood. it works! :>

Answer (score 2):

Just to build on the initial comments

```
a <- c("abc_lvl1", "def_lvl2")

a1 <- do.call(c, lapply(a, function(x){strsplit(x, "_")[[1]][1]}))
a2 <- do.call(c, lapply(a, function(x){strsplit(x, "_")[[1]][2]}))

a1
[1] "abc" "def"
a2
[1] "lvl1" "lvl2"
```